# Getting Value of Y-Axis Max in SSRS

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, axis-labels, reportbuilder3.0

I was wondering if there was anyway to set a value of a data point on a graph equal to the Max auto generated Y-Axis Value.  I have a line chart that i display a single vertical stripLine on for a particular date, but i want that stripLine to go all the way to the top of the chart.  The best I was able to do is set the value to the Max value in the dataset, which works alright, but doesn't render as i'd hope.

[image]

i'd like the vertical black line to extend to the top.  I know I can set the value of that to Max(Fields!Demo.Value) + 10000 and it extends up another 10000, but that usually increases the y-axis max value causing the same spacing issue.  Also, sometime the values are much smaller such as 1000 being the max as opposed to 10mil like in the above graph.

The only other thing I could think was just a clunky IIF statement saying

```
if Max(value) > 1,000,000 
    add 100,000
else if Max(Value) < 1,000,000 and Max(Value) > 500,000
    add 50,000
etc...
```

I understand it'd be in a long IIf() statement, i can figure that out, just seeing if there was any other way by going through the determined y-axis max.